# Laravel query find comma separated and normal string

Tags: php, laravel

I got a column called `fac` that values can be a single number like `2` and also can be comma separated like `2,4,5`

[image]

I want to get data from database via `api`. Also value can be a single or comma separated too. so user can search like these:

`localhost/api/search` `{fac: 1}`

Or

`localhost/api/search` `{fac: 1,4,5}`

I used `find_in_set` but look like it not working in this case:

```
$fac = request('fac');

->whereRaw("find_in_set({$fac}, fac)")->get();
```

If I run this `localhost/api/search` `{fac: 1}` it return nothing, if I run `localhost/api/search` `{fac: 1,4,5}` it give me error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in
>   the call to native function 'find_in_set'

**Goal:**

If user search `1` it should return all data that contains `1`, if search `1,7` should return all data that contains `1` and `7`

Comment: Give this a try ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(" . $fac . ", fac)")->get();

Comment: Never store anything comma separated. Make your table to be in `st normal form with only atomic values for each column.

Comment: @vivek_23 Why? is there any risk or security issue? | after all, if user select multiple option in front, so how you store values in database?

Comment: @tourtravel Then it's a one to many relationship. The reason I said to store values in atomic form is because you will find it a lot easier to maintain. Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) about 1st normal form and read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) about Laravel one to many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert your comma-separated string to an array. And create raw query.

```
$fac = request('fac'); // single value or comma saperated string
$data = explode(',',$fac);
$str='';
$i=1; // to append AND in query

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $str .= 'FIND_IN_SET("'.$value.'" ,fac)';
  if($i < count($data)){
    $str .=' AND '; // use OR as per use
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Now $str will contain raw query

```
FIND_IN_SET("1", fac) AND FIND_IN_SET("7", fac)
```

and you can use in eloquent.

```
->whereRaw($str)->get();
```

Comment: I got error:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `title` like %% and `user_id` =  and FIND_IN_SET("4" fac) AND FIND_IN_SET("2" fac)) in file api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 665`

Comment: comma was missing

Comment: in user id there is nothing ? and also for title ?

Comment: Yes, comma fixed the issue, but it return nothing as `data`

Comment: yes user_id and title are empty, these are optional

Comment: check you have related data or not

Comment: thats why you are not getting data

Comment: if there is no user id not add it in query

Comment: I just noticed one issue Yasin. If user search `1` it return all post contains `1` it good, but if search `1,2` it just return those data exactly contains `1,2` for example this=> `1,2,5,6` not `1,6,2,7`, as I ask in my question, I need to find all data that contains each number. For example if user search `1,2` it should return all posts that contains `1` and also `2` not those contains `1,2`

Comment: Buddy, FIND_IN_SET() used to check the value in comma separated column, so the position of number doesn't matter, i think there is another issue.

Comment: I changed `$str .=' AND ';` =>to=> `$str .=' OR ';` problem fixed :) thanks again